# How to control the speed of four 12 VDC fans across two sources?

Tags: voltage-regulator, fan, pc

I destroyed my fan hub and am trying to replace it with a simple circuit. My PC has a fan header that can power the 12 V DC (not PWM) fans, however, it only supports two fans.

So I am trying to power two more fans off another 12 V source but the second source needs to match the voltage of the header source, as it is controlled internally to regulate speed.

How can I "copy" the voltage of another source?

I'm not too experienced with electronics; am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I went into the BIOS and switched the fan header to voltage regulated and then was able to control the speed on the MSI desktop app.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to buy another fan hub. It will be easier than trying to make anything from scratch.

Comment: yeah, I had a feeling that would be the easiest. Thanks!

Comment: You can very easily copy the voltage with a fan-splitter.